# django: search by ingredients

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a site where users can search for recipes for ingredients, but I can only search by typing 1 ingredient, when I type more than one, the search returns empty. 
**The right search would be the user to insert multiple ingredients and return the recipes that contain those ingredients.** 
I cannot find what's wrong :(

Here are my models.py

```
class Fotos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    linkfoto = models.ImageField()
    nomes = models.ForeignKey('Nomes', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'fotos'


class Ingredientes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ingrediente = models.TextField()
    nomes = models.ForeignKey('Nomes', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'ingredientes'


class Nomes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # AutoField?
    nome = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'nomes'
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Ingredientes, Nomes, Fotos


def post_list(request):
    termo_busca = request.GET.get('pesquisa')
    if termo_busca:
        a = Ingredientes.objects.all().filter(ingrediente__contains=termo_busca)

        # a = a.exclude(ingrediente__icontains=termo_busca!=termo_busca)
        busca = [p.nomes_id for p in a]
        lista = []
        for i in busca:
            nome = Nomes.objects.get(id=i)
            ingredientes = Ingredientes.objects.filter(nomes_id__in=[i])
            foto = Fotos.objects.get(id=i)
            lista.append([nome, ingredientes, foto])

    else:
        a = Nomes.objects.all()[:10]
        cont = len(a)
        lista = []
        for i in range(1, cont):
            nome = Nomes.objects.get(id=i)
            ingredientes = Ingredientes.objects.filter(nomes_id__in=[i])
            foto = Fotos.objects.get(id=i)
            lista.append([nome, ingredientes, foto])

    return render(request, 'aplicacao/post_list.html', {'lista': lista})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use

```
ingrediente__icontains
```

Because in your case words 'Lemon' and 'lemon' not same. I guess that user inputs words for search in html *input* or *textarea*. You need restrict input with some rules. Example users must separate ingredientes using space. See correct search string.

*Lemon fish salt*
Then in your view you need get it ingredientes one by one. See

```
if termo_busca:
    all_ingred = Ingredientes.objects.all()
    searching_ingred = Ingredientes.objects.none()
    for one_ingredient in termo_busca.split():
        searching_ingred = searching_ingred.union(searching_ingred, all_ingred.filter(ingrediente__icontains=one_ingredient))
    # do some with ingredients that match searching
```

Comment: @LíviaVentura ok, i add changes, try it now